# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No source has been specified

Tags: java, csv, exception, weka, arff

I'm using Java to create a program that takes in a CSV file and outputs an Arff file. Whenever the program runs it comes up catching the exception that No source has been specified. When I delete the try catch it comes with the following error and I am not sure why,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No source has been specified 
at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(CSVLoader.java:867) 
at CSVtoArff.Convert(CSVtoArff.java:10) 
at CSVtoArff.main(CSVtoArff.java:23)
```

Below is the code for the program

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import java.io.File;

public class CSVtoArff {
    public static void Convert(String input, String output) throws Exception {
        try {
            CSVLoader load = new CSVLoader();
            load.setSource(new File(input));
            Instances data = load.getDataSet();
            
            
            ArffSaver save = new ArffSaver();
            save.setInstances(data);
            save.setFile(new File(output));
            save.writeBatch();
            System.out.println("File successfully converted");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Does not meet arff standards: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        
            
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String input = "C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\example.csv";
        String output =" C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\example.arff";
        
        Convert(input, output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try putting the files in `C:\temp` folder and change it to below and try.
Sometime windows security my be denying access to protected system folders.
**Also there is an extra leading space in output file path. I have removed that.**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String input = "C:/temp/example.csv";
        String output ="C:/temp/example.arff";
        
        Convert(input, output);
    }
```